# Configure Laravel using Virtualmin on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, apache2, virtualmin

I have recently migrated to a new server, which now uses virtualmin. I'm trying to configure laravel on the new server, but am having trouble with it and cannot find any examples online.

I have downloaded the laravel-project from the old server and saved it in the following directory on the new server:
/home/domain/public_html/laravel-project

My DocumentRoot in /etc/Apache2/sites-available is:

`DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html/public`

I have the following set up in /etc/host:

`MYSQL server listening address (IP)    laravel-project`

My .env file is pointing to the same MySQL server listening address

My index.php file within /home/domain/public_html/laravel-project/public has the following line:

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

I have the following output in the error log:

`[Wed Jun 02 13:26:44.163271 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 1579245:tid 140072238184192] [client 141.101.98.53:14020] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/domain/public_html/public`

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem i solved it with

1. try to upload the application via Virtualmin file manager `(.zip)` and check Extract Compressed.
2. move all the folders and files from `laravel-project` to the `public_html` folder so that it becomes `public_html/app` `public_html/public` etc.
3. No need to change `.conf`, you just need to change folder path in `virtualmin->server configuration->website options` and input your path to `change website document sub-directory`